# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined but my variable is an empty array

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this variable called "groups" that receive values from a redux store:

```
const groups = useSelector(state => state.groupPermissionsStates.groups);
```

My reducer initialize this variable with a empty array:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    groups: [],
    lastPage: 1
}

const groupPermissionsStates = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "REQUEST_GET_GROUPS_PERMISSIONS":
            return {
                ...state,
                groups: action.payload.data,
                lastPage: action.payload.lastPage
            }
            case "CLEAR_GROUPS_PERMISSIONS_LIST":
                return {
                    ...state,
                    groups: [],
                    lastPage: 1
                }
            default:
                return state
    }
}

export default groupPermissionsStates;
```

In my template i'm doing a `group.map()` to go through this array, but i'm receiving:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I check if this variable is changing your value using a useEffect but only print one time and your value is a empty array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(groups)
}, [groups]); // eslint-disable-line
```

When i put an `{ groups && groups.map(group => (` instead of

```
{ groups.map(group => (
```

I don't receive this error and my page launch.

It's my store loading after my component is mounted?
I have other component that i don't use an checker before and runs normally:

```
{users.map(user => (
```

And this users is a variable that have your code based in a redux store:

```
const users = useSelector(state => state.userStates.users);
```

I don't find any difference between this two components, except that the component that use the users variable have an `useEffect()` that make a request to my server and returns the user array filled.

**@Edit:**

This is my root reducer:

```
import userStates from '../modules/users/user.reducer'
import groupPermissionsStates from './group-permissions/group-permissions.reducer'

import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    groupPermissionsStates
    userStates
})
```

My store creation:

```
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
    import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
    import rootReducer from './modules/rootReducer';
    import rootSaga from './modules/rootSaga';


    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const enhancer =
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
        : applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware);
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, enhancer);
    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
    export default store;
```

My index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <SnackbarProvider autoHideDuration={3500} maxSnack={3}>
            <Notifier />
            <AppRouter/>
        </SnackbarProvider>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

My map:

```
{ groups.map(group => (
    <TableRow key={group.id}>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {group.name}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
            {group.inactive === false
                ? "Sim"
                : "Não"}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
            <IconButton
                color="primary"
                aria-label="editar"
                onClick={() => editGroup(group)}
            >
                <EditIcon />
            </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
))}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi i will try to put more code, this is a component with much html tags...

Comment: Updated the question with more code

Comment: I can't find a place where issue can exists. Verify if "REQUEST_GET_GROUPS_PERMISSIONS" is not called before your component is rendered. It can apply undefined to the groups.

Also I can't see your whole component. There is no problem with code snippet that you provided. I would expect to take a look at whole component